# Is there a way to dynamically change a plotly animation axis scale per frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I have an animated plotly scatter graph which plots x,y coordinates normally within the 0-0.5 range with date/time being the frame key. Sometime however I will have to handle anomalous data points which will be well out with this range. I would like the graph to be able to dynamically scale so that the points are not lost off screen. Is this possible?

```
def draw(x1,y1,timestamp):

    d = {
        "x1": x1_trim,
        "y1": y1_trim,
        "time": time_trim
    }
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
  
    fig = px.scatter(df, x="x1", y="y1", animation_frame="time")
    fig.update_yaxes(autorange=True)
    fig.update_xaxes(autorange=True)
    fig.show()
```

I've tried using update_x/yaxes with autorange but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: each frame can have it's own layout, https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html take a look at **frames** definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there is a way to change a plotly animation axis scale per frame. The question remains how *dynamic* it's possible to make it. But if we can say that you've made a few calculations that will let you know which frames you'd like to adjust the ranges for, then a combination of a dict like `yranges = {2002:[0, 200]}` and a for-loop on the frames should do the trick. Let's take a subset of the dataset `px.data.gapminder` as an example. And let's say that you'd like to adjust the range of the yaxis for the frame that displays data for the year `2002` in the following figure:

[image]

Then you can include the following snippet, and get the figure below for `year = 2002`:

```
yranges = {2002:[0, 200]}
for f in fig.frames:
    if int(f.name) in yranges.keys():
        f.layout.update(yaxis_range = yranges[int(f.name)])
```

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
df = df[(df['continent'] == 'Asia') & (df['year'].isin([1997, 2002, 2007]))]

scales = [2002]

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])

yranges = {2002:[0, 200]}

for f in fig.frames:
    if int(f.name) in yranges.keys():
        f.layout.update(yaxis_range = yranges[int(f.name)])

fig.show()
```

Comment: nice ....  we arrived at very similar solutions

Comment: @RobRaymond Yup, sure did!

Answer (score 3):

- each frame can have it's own layout
- after constructing figure, loop over frames and define x & y axis **range**
- code below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": np.tile(pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", freq="1H", periods=12), 10),
        "x": np.random.uniform(1, 4, 120),
        "y": np.random.uniform(2, 5, 120),
    }
)
fig = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y", animation_frame=df["time"].dt.strftime("%H:%M"))

go.Figure(
    data=fig.data,
    frames=[
        fr.update(
            layout={
                "xaxis": {"range": [min(fr.data[0].x) - 0.1, max(fr.data[0].x) + 0.1]},
                "yaxis": {"range": [min(fr.data[0].y) - 0.1, max(fr.data[0].y) + 0.1]},
            }
        )
        for fr in fig.frames
    ],
    layout=fig.layout,
)
```

Comment: This seems promising but when I test this code it seems that plotly tries to smoothly transition to the different ranges but fails horribly leading to a lot of stuttery jumpy nonsense.