# In an animated plotly scatter plot, how to change the axis scale per frame... but in R? (adapt a python solution?)

Tags: python, r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to make an animated plotly graph within R where both axes' min and max change during the animation. Someone recently asked this exact question for python, and it was solved by using layout update and looping through the "frames."

Python solution here: [Is there a way to dynamically change a plotly animation axis scale per frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69584171/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-change-a-plotly-animation-axis-scale-per-frame)

Here is the python code.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
df = df[(df['continent'] == 'Asia') & (df['year'].isin([1997, 2002, 2007]))]

scales = [2002]

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])

yranges = {2002:[0, 200]}

for f in fig.frames:
    if int(f.name) in yranges.keys():
        f.layout.update(yaxis_range = yranges[int(f.name)])

fig.show()
```

I've been looking through the R examples and the R plotly object, and I can't figure out... how would I apply this solution to R?

There's a solution using Shiny here, but the animation is much less smooth, it doesn't have the slider, and I don't know anything about shiny, so I'd rather avoid it if I could: https://community.plotly.com/t/what-is-the-most-performant-way-to-update-a-graph-with-new-data/639/6?u=fabern

In case it's useful, I wrote up my code to start recreating the example in R... as far as I could get.Maybe I need to be using plotly express or dash or some such?

```
library("gapminder")
library('data.table')
  data(package = "gapminder")
  df <- as.data.table(as.data.frame(gapminder))
  df <- df[continent=='Asia' & year %in% c(1997, 2002, 2007)]
  
  graph_animated <- plot_ly(df, x = ~gdpPercap, y = ~lifeExp, frame = ~year, size = ~pop,
                            type = 'scatter', color = ~continent)
```

Comment: if no solution for `plotly` turns up, maybe you'll find `gganimate` helpful, too: https://gganimate.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to build the plot and then add the change. You have to build first, in order to see the frames you want to modify.

```
# build
plt <- plotly_build(graph_animated)

# modify the layout for the second frame
plt$x$frames[[2]]$layout = list(yaxis = list(range = c(0, 200)))
```

After that, you can visualize it as you would any other plot.

[image]

Comment: Ah I didn't understand the build step was a thing, so I was just looking for the "frames" in graph_animated

Comment: I tried this solution though and it seems like it leads to the axes moving around like crazy even if you use the same axes twice in a row? I.e. I tried a graph with 30 frames, and tried to set the first 15 to one y-axis, the second 15 to another, and the whole time the axes are flying around, as if "moving again" to the axis you set from the default one.

For example, if in the example you did, you set all the frames to that same yaxis range, I would expect it to stay static at (0,200), but instead it's moving a ton.

Comment: Actually when I do that, and set all 3 in the example to the same, it looks glitchy the first time I run it, then it looks normal the second time. But in my actual use case, half the frames "fix" on the second run, and the other half don't, and I don't see anything different.

Comment: Instead of "animating" to the new axis from the last axis, in my own use case it is, in all of my first 15 frames, animating from the "original default axis" or something like that. So these 15 frames with the same axis as each other have a crazy animation between each of them.

Comment: In case you end up seeing this, I figured out that at the end of the animation, whatever y-axis range was on the last frame seems to become the new "base" y-axis when you click the "play" button next. And in general, it definitely is doing some sort of animation where it goes from the "base" y-axis to the specific y-axis from that frame, rather than doing from the y-axis from the last frame.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking now. I animated this exactly like what was happening in the Python example (literally). However, I think what you're looking for isn't the same. Let me work on this a bit and see what I can come up with.

Comment: You're my hero Kat, really, thanks for helping me with this! I've spend many hours now trying to figure it out myself. 

I do think I'm looking for the same thing as the python question, although I'm not sure if the python solution has the same problem. I feel like I can't figure out another better way to type/verbalize the problem here, and worst case scenario I could close this and make a new question for it, or edit my question. Let me try to convey it one more time here:

Comment: So in my example, I set frames 1-15 to y-axis (-200,200), and frames 16-31 to (-200,700). I can see the graph_animated object has a layout with (-200,800). That is what I was calling the "base" y-axis... for the whole graph object. But I've saved over every frame, specifically using your solution. 

When I press play, each frame "animates" from (-200,800) to its y-axis its supposed to, instead of animating from the point before. So the y-axis is flying from (-200,800) to (-200, 200) on frame 1, then on frame 2, etc. flying up and down from (-200, 800) to (-200,200).

Comment: I would expect it, instead, to just be animating from (-200,200), the y-axis in frame 1, to (-200,200) again. 

The crazy thing is that each time I press play, it actually uses whatever the final frame's y-axis was as the "base" thing it animates from. So I have different behavior on subsequent "play" presses than the first one, and it's animating from (-200,700), frame 31's y-axis, instead of (-200, 800), the value from the base object.

But it's still animating each point as if it's coming "from" that value. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Also, not sure if this is kosher with stack overflow, but since you're the only one helping me, if we could do a screen share/voice thing I bet you'd fix it really fast, and it'd maybe be a more efficient use of your time. I'm guessing there is just some option somewhere that I can't find that will fix it, and once you see what the issue is it'd be clear to you.

I'm in an R discord server if that would be of interest to you! Or a zoom or whatever would be good. No worries if that's not good for you, though!

Comment: Last tiny thing, I think in your example, if you change your 3rd frame instead of the 2nd one, you'll see the issue! It isn't happening in your solution because the 3rd and 1st frame are the same.

Comment: I've spent a lot of time trying to find a way to coerce `plotly` for this. However, I haven't found a solution. There is an open issue on their Github, because right now frame layout is ignored in animation sequences when calculating the from-to between frames. The've posted this as 'needing a sponsor.' [See here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1687).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks so much for helping me with this, Kat! I really, really appreciate it. The github is an interesting read.

I think I'll just "create" 60 frames between each point in my raw data, create 60 static plots in between each point, export as pictures, and maybe try to bring them into a video editor and see if I can at least make a static video.